# Oracle 12c How to audit specified Stored procedure for specified User

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I would like to audit specific procedure for specific user.
For example i have a stored procedure prc_user_error and i have user which name of Ktd.
When the Ktd user execute prc_user_error procedure should be audited.

I cant use trigger. Also fine grained auditing cant use for execute.
Can you please help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: As per my understanding, You can use a logger table to log the user details as the first step in the procedure.

Comment: almost. but my purpose audit specific user's specific execute procedure's audit record. Assume you issue below syntax and when any user execute prc_user_error procedure, will audited on sys.aud$ audit execute on kata.prc_user_error  by access whenever successful;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting up your procedure like this and test for the name(s) and exit without doing anything in your procedure. If coded correctly than nothing should be printed in my example

```
create or replace procedure sp as
    v_user varchar2(32) := SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' );
   begin  dbms_output.put_line(v_user);
    end;
   /


 begin 
sp; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks looks good. this not audit in sys.aud$ but i can log any other table which i can create.

Answer (score 1):

IDK how you want to audit it, but assume to insert a record into some table:

```
create table myAudit( auditTime TIMESTAMP, auditUser VARCHAR2(30));
```

in procedure:

```
insert into myAudit values (SYSTIMESTAMP, SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV','SESSION_USER') );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But not my question:( I would like to audit when the X user execute P procedure, it should audit on sys.aud$

Comment: Actually i want internal audit mechanism but unfortunately oracle not audit specific procedure for specific user.

Comment: Then edit the question with all the relevant details

Comment: Thank you but i think but question was enough. But i will check again.

Comment: Sometimes you have to actually audit a bit more broadly than you initial intent, then simply filter for the specifics when you query the audit trail.  Say, audit every execution, regardless of the user, then filter on the user in question when querying.

Comment: Thanks. Firstly i thought this and i tried this but my aud$ begun incredible increase size. Here is production banking environment and i stopped audit after i begun to think what can i do more :)